# Is the phrase 'Nec mea dona tibi studio disperta fideli' incorrect?

Tags: vocabulary, grammar-choice, preposition

What is the difference between

> **Ne** mea dona tibi studio disperta fideli

and

> **Nec** mea dona tibi studio disperta fideli

and is the latter version, which differs in the single letter 'c' only,  wrong?

**Remarks.**

- This is a line from a famous poem of Lucretius.
- This line, together with the one immediately following it, appears as the epigraph of quite a few, and quite different, 18th- and 19th century texts.
- The second version does appear in the epigraph, but more rarely than the first line, which of course suggests that the second version is less correct.
- My Latin is sadly much too rusty to understand what the difference between the two versions is.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These four verses from *De Rerum Natura* employ a [negative purpose clause](http://www.thelatinlibrary.com/101/UtClauses.pdf), which uses the conjunction *nē* + the subjunctive.

> Quod superest, vacuas auris animumque sagacem
>   semotum a curis adhibe veram ad rationem,
>   ne mea dona tibi studio disposta fideli,
>   intellecta prius quam sint, contempta relinquas.
>
> For the rest, ears unpreoccupied and keen intelligence
>   detached from cares you should apply to true philosophy, that my
>   gifts, set forth for you with faithful solicitude, may not by you be
>   contemptuously discarded before they have been apprehended.

<sub><sup>([Loeb Classics, *De Rerum Natura* 1.51](https://www.loebclassics.com/view/lucretius-de_rerum_natura/1924/pb_LCL181.7.xml))</sup></sub>

The conjunction *nec* is an apocopated form of *neque*, which in a negative purpose clause means *et nē*. As far as English translation goes, the difference between *nec* and *nē* would simply be, "and that my gifts... may not by you be..." versus "that my gifts... may not by you be..." The difference consists of a single word, whether or not to add "and" in front.

Both versions are metrically correct. It's worth mentioning that *nec* is long by position whereas *nē* is long by nature. I'm not sure why one is more common, or why two versions exist in the first place. I'll leave it for someone else to explain that point.

Comment: But an 'and' doesn't actually make sense here, because there's nothing for it to connect this purpose clause to. The sentence has a main clause + single purpose clause. Although neque/nec is sometimes used instead of neve/neu to add a **second** purpose clause, I know of know place where it's used instead of simple ne, and I don't see any way to make this reading work. All I can think is that, when the line was taken out of context for use as an epigraph, the fact that it was originally part of a purpose clause became obscured, and therefore the erroneous 'correction' of ne to nec crept in.

Comment: @cnread Yeah, it's possible if not likely that *nec* is simply an error. I only deduced that if it were to work, then it would have the meaning of *et ne* in a purpose clause; that this would be the most appropriate meaning of *nec*, although *nec* itself might not be appropriate.